# Counting with parameters

Tags: bash

I am  learning bash scripting and having some difficulties with the basics.
So my first exercise was to make a simple bash script count from 1 to 10.

I solved that one easily with

```
for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; done
```

Now I'm  trying one more difficult, which is doing the same, but using parameters.

I have to assign $1 to "a" and $2 to "b" so I can presumably use the code with
 `{a..b}`
 instead of

```
{1..10}
```

And be able to use the command

```
bash scriptname 1 10
```

for example, to get my script to count.

On top of that I want to add a control mechanism that makes sure the $1 value is smaller than the $2 mechanism, so I would get an error message
For example, if I were to use

```
bash scriptname  8 6
```

I would get the error

```
8 is bigger than 6, please enter a new starting value.
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can make this work?

EDIT:

So I got a bit further.

I got the original part to work with

```
a=$1
b=$2
for((i=a; i<= b; i++)) do echo $i; done
```

So far so good, but now I'm trying to add the error message and the ability to re-enter the $1 command after my script says it's too big.

I'm trying to do this with

```
while [a>b]
echo $a is bigger then $b, please enter a new number:
read a done
```

But I can't get any of that last part to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Read the manual, attempt to do the homework.

Comment: `info bash` might help.  Also note that brace expansion happens before variable expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `(( ... ))` for arithmetic conditions:

```
a=$1
b=$2
if (( a > b )) ; then
    echo $a is bigger than $b
    exit 1
fi
```

Also note that `{a..b}` only works for literals, as brace expansion happens before variable expansion. So, for variables, you have to use `seq` or a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for this!

I got a bit further into it, it's not completely done but I wanted to show my progress.

a=$1
b=$2
for((i=a; i<= b; i++)) do echo $i;done
while [a>b]
echo $a is bigger then $b
read a done

Only problem I have now is that my terminal gives me an ""unexpected end of line" error, and I can't get the read a to work.

Comment: Why don't use arithmetic operators of `test` (or `[` or `[[`) ?

Comment: @IdrissNeumann: Because `(( ... ))` (arithmetic evaluation) has simpler syntax (as demonstrated in this answer) and more features. `test` / `[` are only needed for POSIX compliance; `[[` requires bash, so you may as well use `((`. Note that arithmetic _expansion_ - `$(( ... ))` - *is* part of the POSIX standard).

Comment: @mklement0 `[[` is available since KSH-88 ;)

Comment: @IdrissNeumann: Good to know, but I was only referring to the distinction between what's safe to use in `bash` vs. what's safe to use in a POSIX-features-only `sh`, which `bash` is a superset of.

Comment: Yes and I agree with you. I just prefer to use `[[` to do that kind of test.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like :

```
if [[ $1 -gt $2 ]]; then
    echo "$1 is bigger than $2 !";
    exit 1
fi
```

Or :

```
if [ "$1" -gt "$2" ]; then
    echo "$1 is bigger than $2 !";
    exit 1
fi
```

Or :

```
if test "$1" -gt "$2"; then
    echo "$1 is bigger than $2 !";
    exit 1
fi
```

Of course, you could use `test` or `[` or `[[` in a loop like this :

```
while [[ $a -gt $b ]]; do
    echo "$a is bigger than $b !";
    read a
done
```

See `man test` to get more details about arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with following code:

```
a=$1
b=$2
while [ $b -lt $a]; do
echo “$a is bigger than $b, please enter a new value.”
read a
done
for((i=a; i<=b; i++)) do echo “$i”;
done
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Your code won't work as posted - run it through http://shellcheck.net to see the specific problems; that site is a great resource in general. Also, I suggest substituting `(( b < a ))` for `[ $b -lt $a ]`, as in @choroba's answer.